# <p:commandbutton> not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

i am new to JSF and primefaces.. i wrote a small code... i am getting what i want to do with "h:commandbutton" but samething is not working with "p:commandbutton". is there any difference between the functionality of these two things.

```
<h:commandButton value= "enter" actionListener= "#{newJSFManagedBean.show()}"/><br/>
<p:commandButton value= "enter" actionListener= "#{newJSFManagedBean.show()}"/><br/>
```

i have tried alot of things, but newjsfmanagedbean.show() havenot been called from p:commandbutton but h:commandbutton is working fine. what is the reason :-( ?

Comment: It has to be inside a form.

Comment: it is inside "h:form" .

Comment: Then show us the entire code (html + backing bean)

Comment: Try with action instead of actionListener. You could also try ajax="false".

Comment: Could you please share your show() function as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't share your show() function but I can guess that it looks like below :

```
public void show(ActionEvent event) {
    // some stuff here
}
```

Well, just delete your brackets in your EL language if you want to use it with primefaces :

```
<p:commandButton value= "enter" actionListener= "#{newJSFManagedBean.show}"/>
```

Otherwise it looks for a show method which does not have any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

**hey it worked :-) **
thanxmates

```
<p:commandButton process="@this" value= "enter"  ajax="false" actionListener= "#{newJSFManagedBean.show}" /><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `process="@this"` to `p:commandButton` to get its action invoked. If you want to process any other components add `process="@this,id1,id2"` like this.

Hope this helps